# send request in python but data used as xml with parent / child node

Tags: python

I am sending a request from python using the below code and its working fine

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'ID':'45678','MAN':'11512C'}

session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://admin.example.com/login.php',headers=headers,data=payload)
```

but now I need to change my data to multi tags for ex:

```
<Input> 
<PO>
<ID>45678</ID>
<MAN>11512C</MAN>
</PO>
</Input>
```

Then how can I modify my payload

```
payload = {"Input:{"PO:{'ID':'45678','MAN':'11512C'}}}
```

Comment: Use a xml parser like lxml: http://lxml.de/

Comment: I am using lxml but the way I am passing payload is correct means syntax or not?

Comment: Using `payload` is sending the data form-encoded. That bascially ist a list of key-value pairs. The server seems to understand this. Does it also understand structured data as the XML you describe? What format does the server accept?

Comment: when send the same data as xml , its working fine

Comment: *How* do you send it as XML? What do you want to do instead?

Comment: in my code 
r = requests.request(method, urlcomp, headers=headers, data=payload,verify=False)

where data=payloadis passed from a text file.
in text file I provide payload = {"Input:{"PO:{'ID':'45678','MAN':'11512C'}}}

Now when code dosent work then to test it from xml I used 
data  = open('C:\INFO.xml', 'rb').read

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't put code in a comment.